# What is the feasibility of a Coanda/Magnus effect wing airplane?

Tags: aircraft-design

It seems the EU granted some hundreds of thousand € to a non-engineer, to study a cargo airplane with a turning cylinder in the leading edge, to produce increased lift by the Coanda/Magnus effect also used in the Flettner rotor sails for ships. As the concept seems having been discarded because of the important gyroscope effect of the turning barrel: anybody commenting about technical reasons for this revival of a discarded concept?

Comment: The answer to this can only ever really be speculation. The researcher's hope, however, seemed to be that modern composite materials meant that the extra lift could now compensate the extra weight. The big problem other than weight (which was never solved), however, is that if the aircraft loses power it loses lift, just at the moment it needs it most.

Comment: Can you include references in your question?

Comment: An historical report about Magnus/Coanda wing airplanes exists in the German publication: 'Luftfahrt', nr 22, pag 3415-3430, Dipl. -Ing H. J. Lindstaedt (Lindstädt), 'Flugzeuge mit Walzenflügeln', Mittler & S. GmbH, Herford, 1978, ISBN 3 87547 185 7                                          Some info is in the Wikipedia article: 'Fanwing', including the reference/link to a review technical article in english (offered to be purchased)

Answer (score 4):

A lot of research grants are wasted on scams or projects making exorbitant claims. See it this way: The people who judge an idea grant-worthy need to spend the money they have available somehow, and if they were clever enough to pick winners all the time, they would not work in a government bureaucracy.

On the other hand, who is to judge what idea is really good before it has been tried? You have to accept some losses if you want to move outside of safe bets - only then can new ground be broken.

NASA funded a [researcher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_Wolkovitch) for more than three decades who was only working on joined wing projects. It's easy to see that they are a non-starter, but this guy built his career on that particular hoax.

Comment: Agencies get money, if not spend in year, amount they get next year is reduced. Also, there's a patent for a 5-Stroke, double expansion Int Comb Eng, US 2002/0050253 Schmitz. Bourgogne Uni, P Leclaire, worked on it, Otto build the same: 1879, CT company EHV build car with this type of engine, 1906 (T Suzuki), 2 Spanish patents: 0156621, 1942,  Jimeno-Cataneo; 0433850 Ubierna-Laciana 1975, on the same. Somebody applied for patent Wankel Engine Rotor, but was described 1982, D W Garside SAE paper. 'Fanwing', had EU grant: see Wikipedia: 'Fanwing': 'A review of Magnus effect in aeronautics'.

Comment: J. WOLKOVITCH.  "The joined wing - An overview", Journal of Aircraft, Vol. 23, No. 3 (1986), pp. 161-178. 
https://doi.org/10.2514/3.45285 Is this? Or this one:
NASA-CR- 172529 , 19850008520 'Aerodynamic-Structural Study of Canard Wing, Dual Wing, and Conventional Wing Systems for GA Applications' BP Selberg, DL Cronin. University of Missouri, Rolla

Comment: @Urquiola: Yes, of course, Julian Wolkovitch.